# clusterExport, enviroment and function scoping

Tags: r, parallel-processing, environment-variables, scoping

im new in parallel computing with R, im using the parallel library. I have several functions that are currently located in the global env and a function called main_fun, which call all of these functions. But i get an error that some functions from another library is not define, depsite the fact that i declared within the clusterExport

```
fun1 <- function(data, pob){
     pob_n <- ifelse(pob == 1, T, F)
     weights  <- parSapply(cl, 1:nrow(pob_n), function(comb) data[pob_n[comb, ], "wei"] %>% sum())
     punt <- parSapply(cl, 1:nrow(pob_n), function(comb) data[pob_n[comb, ], "Pun"] %>% sum())
     result <- cbind(weights, punt, pob_n)  %>% as.data.frame()
     return(result) 
}

main_fun <- function(data) {
  n <- nrow(data)
  N <- 200

  cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 0) # Generando el cluster r
  clusterExport(cl, list("n", "N", "data", "fun1"), envir = environment()) 
  clusterEvalQ(cl, {library(tidyverse)
                   library(parallel)}) 
  
  pob <- parSapply(cl, 1:N, function(iteration) sample(c(0, 1), n, replace = T)) %>% t() 
  gen_0 <- fun1(data= data, pob= pob)
  stopCluster(cl) 
  return(gen_0 * 10)
}
```

i get the following error:

```
 Error in parSapply(cl, 1:nrow(pob), function(comb) data[pob[comb,  : 
  object 'cl' not found
```

what could be wrong?, i've just tried to pass the "cl" variable in the clusterExport function, and i still get the same error. The only solution that i had found is to put all the functions inside the main function, but i still want to know what its going on.

Comment: You aren't passing the `cl` value to your `fun1` function. The `cl` variable is local to your `main_fun` function. You should pass that value as an additional parameter. It should not be included in the clusterExport. This really isn't unique to parallel. This is just how variable scoping works in R.

Comment: A follow up on MrFlick comment: Regardless, you _cannot_ pass 'cluster' obects to another R process.  That is, even if you export `cl` explicitly, or pass it as an argument, the object will be _invalid_ in another R process.  That `cluster` object only works in the main R session where it was created.